# ASP.NET Logged In Template isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm using ASP.NET Membership for a web-application and currently cannot get the LoggedIn Template to display the email address of the user once they are logged in. This is very frustrating as the login is working but the LoggedIn template just doesn't seem to be working.

```
 <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        <br />
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="/Account/Login.aspx"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
                <br />
            <asp:HyperLink ID = "lblAccountEdit" runat = "server" Text = "Edit Account" NavigateUrl = "Admin/AdminHome.aspx"></asp:HyperLink><br />
            <asp:HyperLink ID = "lblReturn" runat = "server" Text = "Return to Search" NavigateUrl = "UserPages/Search/Search.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>

 </div>
```

Any help on this will be gratefully received.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use inline expression in LoggedInTemplate <%=Membership.GetUser().Email %>